# Testing Pinterest with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, pinterest

I've succesfully installed Jmeter and setup the recording. I added the next config elements: HTTP Cookie Manager, HTTP Cache Manager with clear cache every iteration enabled. I'm using Firefox and Jmeter is recording everything that I do in the browser.

But I have one problem: when I go to pinterest.com I receive a white page with black text. Every other website is working like it suppose, but I want to test only Pinterest. When I try to setup a new account...the same: white page with black text. Something is not loading correctly and I don't know what.

Can someone help me with a hint?

Answer (score 0):

When you to through the proxy, your browser doesn't trust HTTPS traffic anymore, because the proxy replaces the certificates. If your page is a HTTP page that uses HTTPS resources like Style Sheets or JS files, you get what you're describing - a plain black text site on white background - where graphic buttons don't work anymore.

If you use firebug to inspect your traffic, you will see the resources that are not loading because of HTTPS certificate issues. You can either add exceptions to your browser to load these resources, or as @aleix suggested you can use a browser plugin like Blazemeter to record scripts without going through a proxy.

See [here](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering to my problem. I've resolved the issue by importing manually the certificate created by Jmeter in his bin folder to Firefox.

It was, indeed, a https certificate problem, but I'd managed it because of your feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Try blazemeter extension for chrome, is a recorder http request like proxy server of JMeter, and maybe it wil allow you to record correctly in pinterest

Comment: Suggesting a completely different tool isn't really an answer to a question about an issue with a different tool.

Comment: its an extension, you record the script and then export it to JMeter. But You are right,